# Как из одной таблицы передать значение в другую таблицу

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ооп

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно из таблицы shop_order_items передать в таблицу shop_vmeste_order значение поля quantity. Передать его нужно в поле total. То-есть по итогу должно получиться total = quantity. С Джоинами не особо дружу..

```
       $order_model = new shopOrderModel(); // дефолтная модель
    $order = $order_model->getOrder($order_id);

    $vmesteCheck = false;
    foreach($order['items'] as $item) {
        if($item['sku_code'] != $this->plugin->getSettings('skuCodeIdentifier')) {
            $vmesteCheck = false; 
            break;
        }
        $vmesteCheck = true;
    }

    if ($vmesteCheck && $order['state_id']=="paid" || $order['state_id']=="new" || $order['state_id']=="processing") {
        $data = array(
            'order_id' => $order['id'],
            'contact_id' => $order['contact_id'],
            'datetime' =>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'total' => 1,             //$order['total']
            'status' => "processing",
        );
```

'total' => $order['quantity'] - не работает так как $order это таблица shop_order

Comment: Киньте структуры таблиц, или хотя бы напишите что у них общего, через что можно эти join'ы прописать?

Comment: GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON alltest.database5 TO 'sam'@'localhost';

Comment: Общее у них только order_id

Comment: По сути это товары у которых есть количество (quantity), в total нужно прописать quantity выбранного товара, выбрать можно по order_id

Comment: Можно к первой таблице добавить кол-во со второй через left join.. Поскольку вы своей структуры не скинули, то вот вам абстрактный пример -> `SELECT table1.*, table2.quantity FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.order_id = table1.order_id`

Comment: $quants = "SELECT shop_order_items *, shop_vmeste_order.quantity FROM shop_order_items LEFT JOIN shop_vmeste_order ON shop_vmeste_order.order_id = shop_order_items.order_id" ,   'total' => $quants['quantity'],  сделал так, выдает значение 0